# Laravel authorizing actions using Policies via Blade Templates

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, policy

I created a Policy via this command and registered the policy:

```
php artisan make:policy PostPolicy --model=Post
```

There is an update policy method already included in the class:

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

Now I want to use the @can directive:

```
@can('update', $post)
    <!-- The Current User Can Update The Post -->
@endcan
```

But I get this error message: "Undefined variable: post"

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: did you pass the $post the blade file form you controller ? like `return view('view.name',['post' =>  $post])`

Comment: No :( There is a index.blade.php file and a show.blade.php file. But the show.blade.php is included in the index.blade.php. The data for the show.blade.php is loaded via AJAX. I want to hide some buttons if the user is not the author. I suppose then it does not work?

Comment: I'm confused! Please provide more details in you question like controller file code , blade file code !

Comment: This is not possible because all data is loaded via AJAX. The blade files rendered once. I marked your comment as useful :)